# telegram bot api. Как уменьшить размер кнопок? (Java)

Tags: java, telegram-bot, button

```
        KeyboardRow row = new KeyboardRow();
        row.add("1");
        keyboard.add(row);

        row = new KeyboardRow();
        row.add("2");
        keyboard.add(row);


        row = new KeyboardRow();
        row.add("3");
        keyboard.add(row);
```

Как уменьшить размер кнопок? ( имеется в виду самой рамки с кнопками) [image: ]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если открыть документацию, то много чего интересного можно узнать. Например то, что у клавиатуры есть параметр `resize_keyboard`, который в Вашем случае нужно установить на `true`:

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup

Comment: огромное спасибо! Извините, если вопрос был слишком глупый. Я только учусь :)

Comment: Ничего страшного, мы все когда-то учились :)